# Why does the pattern ignore the space inside character class

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match some codes that are short strings with simple structure:

- 5 digits
- Colon
- Some letters
- **Space or underscore**
- Some digits.

I want to use a `Pattern.COMMENT` option to format my pattern:

```
String pat = "(?x) ([0-9]{5}) : ([a-zA-Z]+ [_ ] [0-9]+) ";
```

This pattern works fine at https://regex101.com/r/oW8vQ4/1.

However, in Java, this line:

```
"31500:STR 200".matches(pat)
```

yields *false*.

**Why does it return *false* here? Shouldn't the `[_ ]` match the space even if the `Pattern.COMMENT` is enabled as it is inside a character class?**

Comment: "Shouldn't the [_ ] match the space even if the Pattern.COMMENT is enabled as it is inside a character class?" - where'd you get that idea?

Comment: Well, it worked like that at regex101.

Comment: Yeah, in PHP regexes. Regex implementations have all kinds of incompatibilities; you need to check the documentation for the implementation you're using.

Comment: I see it now, I think I need to switch to some other online regex tester that supports Java regex. Is there one with highlighting capabilities like  regex101?

Comment: @user2357112: To be clear, only Java does this. So it can be seen as a rule where Java (what a surprise) is the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need to scape the space inside the character classes. From http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html

> Java, however, does not treat a character class as a single token in free-spacing mode. Java does ignore whitespace and comments inside character classes. So in Java's free-spacing mode, [abc] is identical to [ a b c ]. To add a space to a character class, you'll have to escape it with a backslash. But even in free-spacing mode, the negating caret must appear immediately after the opening bracket. [ ^ a b c ] matches any of the four characters ^, a, b or c just like [abc^] would. With the negating caret in the proper place, [^ a b c ] matches any character that is not a, b or c.

Give it a try with the pattern - just added `\\` before the space... but didn't test this myself.

```
String pat = "(?x) ([0-9]{5}) : ([a-zA-Z]+ [_\\ ] [0-9]+) ";
```